# WPF: DataTemplate-Style gets only applied if the Command can execute

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Another strange behavior in my MVVM-Adventures I can't explain and didn't find a reasoning:
I have a Command in my VM, which can be executed, when a Color is selected:

```
    public ICommand SetSingleColor
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(f =>
            {
                var visualLed = f as VisualLed;
                visualLed.Color = SelectedColor.Value;
            }, () => SelectedColor.HasValue);
        }
    }
```

My DataTemplate is looking like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ml:VisualLed}" x:Key="DtVisualLed">
    <Button 
        Background="DarkCyan"
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SetSingleColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=v:LedDesignView}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        Style="{StaticResource StyleBtnLed}">
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

As u can see, I pass the VisualLed itself back to the VM, so I can set the Color. I just added the Background-Property for testing purposes.
What I really don't get: The Style and also the Background are only applied, if the Command can be executed! So if I load the View, the Button-Background is the Default-Gray, and as soon as I select a Color, it becomes DarkCyan.

Unfortunately, I can't give more Informations, but I didn't find anything on the Topic, how ButtonBase.Command influences other Properties. It also seems like a expected behavior, since I don't get any Binding-Errors or such.

Comment: Is your button disabled until you select a color? Can you click on it?

Comment: Yes, it is disabled, until I select a Color. This is expected and what I want, but I don't get why the Style isn't applied until then, since I don't see any direct correlation between the Style/Background and the Command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is relation between Button.Command and Button.IsEnabled property. If Command.CanExecute returns false, button becomes disabled. Now, you often cannot control everything with your own style, if control developer did not plan for this. In this case, disabled button background is fixed by developers of the Button and you cannot override it with your own style (unless you change Template of the button).

Comment: Hm, you're absolutely right. What I don't get: I can overwrite the Style on Buttons, which are enabled, but not when it's disabled, then I have to overwrite the whole DataTemplate. How is this distinction done?

Comment: Basically by developer of Button class. He could for example had exposed DisabledBackground property, then in template use it for disabled button, but did not. Instead he somehow hardcoded this value inside his template, that is why you have to overwrite whole template to fix this.

Comment: Well it's Microsoft itself then, since it's a plain default button. Interesting stuff, I will have to overwrite the whole Template then indeed.